# Windows XP does not recognize any portable media

Tags: windows, windows-xp, usb, usb-storage

When I try to use **any** USB mass storage device it does not show up in "My Computer".

The PC recognizes that they are attached (they are in Device Manager, show up in Hardware and in Admin Tools under Disc Drives). It's not a problem with the USB ports themselves.

I've tried uninstalling all USB ports in device manager and rebooting but it still does not recognize any portable media.

Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open up: **Start -> Settings -> Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Computer Management**

In this tool, Select the **Disk Management** section from the tree on the left (should be under **Storage**). Make sure that the USB drives are showing up in the list of volumes.

You should be able to right-click on the USB Drive (assuming it's listed there) and select **Change Drive Letter and Paths ...** which will allow you to designate a drive letter for your USB drive. If it already has one, try changing the drive letter it's trying to use.

Open up your **My Computer** again to see if the drive letter you have just assigned shows up.

Answer (score 3):

Check in Disk Management and see if they are showing up there.

I have only seen this once about five years ago and never found what caused it, but it sounds a bit similar - drives are detected and installed, but no drive letter is assigned.

If they are showing in device manager, right click on the volume and try to manually assign a letter/mount point.

If they are not in disk management, sorry, but without more information, I am not sure I can help.

Comment: heh, I ninja'd you. :) But your suggestion is essentially the same as mine. +1